# SASS Optimize Borders Into one line of Code

Tags: css, sass

I am not sure if this is possible or not. But I feel like there should be a way to do this. I am using SASS and I am trying to find a way to optimize borders. I would like to be able to define my border sides sizes, type, and color all in one line.

There are instances where I have 1,2, or 3 borders. And what I would like to do is. Write something using SASS where all properties can be defined in one line. The problem is..

`border-left`: `border-right:` `border-top:` and `border-bottom:`

Are all separate selectors and I would like to combine them.

What I am thinking of doing is something like this...

**SUDO CODE:**

```
border ($top,$left,$right,$bottom, $type, $color);

#div {
    @include border(1px, 1px, 1px, 0, solid, #CCC);
}
```

I was thinking something along these lines would be close... but again the problem is combining all border selectors into one line so that is outputs as valid CSS.

```
@mixin borders {
  border:($top,$left,$right,$bottom, $type, $color);
}
```

Using a @mixin is all wrong, I am pretty sure of this... So any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: CSS can do this. See http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_shorthand_reference#Border

Comment: Please read my comment on maxbeaty's post... I am aware of how to create borders with straight CSS. There are complex reasons as to why I am using SASS to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking to do something similar and ended up with this @mixin.

```
@mixin border ($style,  $sides...){

    @if ($style != "") {

        @if ($sides == "") {

            border: $style;

        } @else {

            @each $side in $sides {

               @if ($side == 'top' or
                    $side == 'right' or
                    $side == 'bottom' or
                    $side == 'left') {

                    border-#{$side}: $style;

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yep - I've used it quite a lot.

Comment: Is there an example of how to use this mixin?

Comment: @pixeltooth this helped me figure it out: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments

Comment: Here's my example, using sass: `+border(2px solid shade($ccblue, 10%), bottom, right)`

Comment: Is there a complete example of this mixin? I still didn't figure out how to use it. Please send us a working version. You could use SassMeister here http://www.sassmeister.com/

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility:

```
@mixin border( $coordinates: 0 0 0 0, $colour: #000000, $style: solid ) {
  $top: nth($coordinates, 1);
  $right: nth($coordinates, 2);
  $bottom: nth($coordinates, 3);
  $left: nth($coordinates, 4);

  @if not(unitless($top)) {
    border-top: $top $style $colour;
  }
  @if not(unitless($right)) {
    border-right: $right $style $colour;
  }
  @if not(unitless($bottom)) {
    border-bottom: $bottom $style $colour;
  }
  @if not(unitless($left)) {
    border-left: $left $style $colour;
  }

}

$side: 1px;
@include border($side 0 $side 0, black);
```

CSS Output:

```
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```

This way you can avoid having to overwrite styles, but I'd still rather use normal css shorthand if you need to target all the border sides.

Could probably extend this to output the shorthand property if a single $coordinates value is passed. That way at least you can standardise all your border style calls.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, as there was no reply to my comment here is how I am using the mixin from the best answer:

```
@mixin border($style, $color, $sides) {
    @if ($style != "") {

        @if ($sides == "") {
            border: $style $color;

        } @else {
            @each $side in $sides {
               @if ($side == 'top' or
                    $side == 'right' or
                    $side == 'bottom' or
                    $side == 'left') {

                    border-#{$side}: $style $color;
                }
            }
        }  

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
.use-border {
   @include border(1px solid, #22222, bottom right);
}
```

You can define multiple directions on the last argument. Nice and helpful mixin!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version. It's not perfect, but it's short.

```
@mixin border($side, $style) {
  @if $side == all {
border: $style;
  } @else {
border-#{$side}: $style;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@mixin  border($color: $white, $opacity: 1,$width : 1px,$style : solid, $position: '') {

  @if $position != '' {
    $position : "-#{$position}";
  }
  border#{$position}:#{$width } #{$style} #{$color};
  border#{$position}:#{$width } #{$style} #{rgba($color,$opacity)};
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need a mixin. You can [use plain CSS as documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border):

> The border CSS property is a shorthand property for setting the individual border property values in a single place in the style sheet. border can be used to set the values for one or more of: border-width, border-style, border-color.

Example of setting the width, style, and color of al the borders using the shorthand:

```
border: 1px solid #CCC
```

That will apply to each side in just one line. You can then override a particular side if you wish for it to be different:

```
border: 1px solid #CCC
border-top: 0
```

Comment: I understand how to do this with plain CSS. If I wanted to do that I wouldn't have asked how to do it with SASS. The reason I want to do it this way, is because I am using a code base where lots of properties are used through out a variety of different mixins / selectors. And it needs to be customizable in a way where we don't have to keep re-writing multiple lines of CSS when we can just write one.

Comment: Total characters you have to type to use your proposed mixin: 57. Total characters you have to type to use plain CSS: 36. You don't need to use a pre-processor for everything. Sometimes, as is the case here, built in shorthands of plain CSS are simpler and more straightforward.